# Proof about Limit Supremum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> Prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n$ is absolutely convergent if $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\dfrac{1}{n}} <1$

Well if $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\dfrac{1}{n}} <1$  then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n$ converges for all $|x|<R$ where $R=\dfrac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\dfrac{1}{n}}}$
And as it is $<1$ $R>1$ and so there exists an interval $[-R,R]$ that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n$ converges, as R>1, this limit will always include 0.
So $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n 0^n$=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n$ converges absolutely

Is this correct?

Comment: You must take the value of power serie at $1$ and not at $0$ to get back the serie $\sum a_n$

Comment: Please avoid the ugly `|a_n|^{\dfrac{1}{n}}`, each occurrence to be replaced by `|a_n|^{1/n}`.